# Edit derived WinForm MenuStrip

Tags: .net, winforms, visual-studio-2010

I have a WinForm base class with a `protected MenuStrip`. Is it possible (in the designer) to edit the `MenuStrip` items in a derived `Form`? I've tried with both `public` and `protected`, no difference. `Buttons` and `Panels` works fine, I can edit both in a derived `Form`.

I can of course do it programatically, but that's not what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at the [EnableDesignMode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.design.controldesigner.enabledesignmode.aspx) method.